# flushing printf statements in PAM module

Tags: linux, unix, pam

I wrote a PAM module with an authentication process which outputs status messages with time delay.

```cpp
int pam_sm_authenticate(pam_handle_t *pamh, int flags, int argc, const char **argv) {

    printf("Welcome to my PAM Module ... authentication\n");

    /* doing something which lasts about 30 seconds */

    printf("Authentication successfull!\n");
    return PAM_SUCCESS;
}
```

The problem is that the authentication process (tested with sshd) does not output anything for 30 seconds. Then both lines appear at the same time.

```
Welcome to my PAM Module ... authentication
Authentication successfull!
```

I need that the first line appears immediately and the second line appears 30 seconds later.

kind regards